# Two button functionality in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, magnific-popup

I'm trying to combine the functionality of two buttons into one. This is a program that enables/disables a text or image magnifier. If I enable the zoomer than I want both the text and image to magnify if they are hovered on and vice versa with disable.

**How should I edit the function/code to reflect one button that controls the magnification of both image and text?**

This is the function I believe is controlling the button and zooming:

```
$("button").click(function() {
        var state = $(this).text(); // enable or disable
        $(".zoom:eq(" + $(this).attr('data-id') + ")").anythingZoomer(state);
        $(this).text((state === "disable") ? "enable" : "disable");
        return false;
      });
```

The full project is below

```js
;
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {

  "use strict";
  $.anythingZoomer = function(el, options) {
    var n, o, t, base = this;
    base.$wrap = $(el);
    base.wrap = el;

    // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
    base.$wrap.data('zoomer', base);

    base.version = '2.2.6';

    base.init = function() {
      base.options = o = $.extend({}, $.anythingZoomer.defaultOptions, options);

      // default class names
      n = $.anythingZoomer.classNames;

      // true when small element is showing, false when large is visible
      base.state = true;
      base.enabled = true;
      base.hovered = false;

      base.$wrap.addClass(n.wrap).wrapInner('<span class="' + n.wrapInner + '"/>');
      base.$inner = base.$wrap.find('.' + n.wrapInner);
      base.$small = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.smallArea);
      base.$large = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.largeArea);

      base.update();

      // Add classes after getting size
      base.$large.addClass(n.large);
      base.$small.addClass(n.small);

      base.$inner
        .bind('mouseenter' + n.namespace, function() {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          base.saved = base.enabled;
          base.hovered = true;
          if (o.delay) {
            clearTimeout(base.delay);
            base.enabled = false;
            base.delay = setTimeout(function() {
              base.enabled = base.saved;
              base.position.type = 'mousemove';
              base.$inner.trigger(base.position);
              base.reveal();
            }, o.delay);
          } else {
            base.reveal();
          }
        })
        .bind('mouseleave' + n.namespace, function() {
          base.hovered = false;
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          if (o.delay) {
            clearTimeout(base.delay);
            base.enabled = base.saved;
          }
          if (base.state && base.enabled) {
            // delay hiding to prevent flash if user hovers over it again
            // i.e. moving from a link to the image
            base.timer = setTimeout(function() {
              if (base.$zoom.hasClass(n.windowed)) {
                base.hideZoom(true);
              }
            }, 200);
          }
        })
        .bind('mousemove' + n.namespace, function(e) {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          base.position = e;
          if (!base.hovered) {
            return;
          }
          if (base.state && base.enabled) {
            clearTimeout(base.timer);
            // get current offsets in case page positioning has changed
            // Double demo: expanded text demo will offset image demo zoom window
            var off = base.$small.offset();
            base.zoomAt(e.pageX - off.left, e.pageY - off.top, null, true);
          }
        })
        .bind(o.switchEvent + (o.switchEvent !== '' ? n.namespace : ''), function() {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          // toggle visible image
          if (base.state) {
            base.showLarge();
          } else {
            base.showSmall();
          }
        });

      base.showSmall();

      // add events
      $.each('initialized zoom unzoom'.split(' '), function(i, f) {
        if ($.isFunction(o[f])) {
          base.$wrap.bind(f, o[f]);
        }
      });

      base.initialized = true;
      base.$wrap.trigger('initialized', base);

    };

    base.reveal = function() {
      base.enabled = base.saved;
      if (base.state && base.enabled) {
        base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeIn(o.speed);
        if (o.overlay) {
          base.$overlay.addClass(n.overlay);
        }
        base.$smInner.addClass(n.hovered);
        base.$wrap.trigger('zoom', base);
      }
    };

    base.update = function() {

      // make sure the large image is hidden
      if (base.initialized) {
        base.showSmall();
      }

      base.$smInner = (base.$small.find('.' + n.smallInner).length) ?
        base.$small.find('.' + n.smallInner) :
        base.$small.wrapInner('<span class="' + n.smallInner + '"/>').find('.' + n.smallInner);
      base.$small.find('.' + n.overly).remove();

      if (o.clone) {
        t = base.$smInner.clone()
          .removeAttr('id')
          .removeClass(n.smallInner)
          .addClass(n.largeInner);
        if (base.$large.length) {
          // large area exists, just add content
          base.$large.html(t.html());
        } else {
          // no large area, so add it
          t.wrap('<div class="' + o.largeArea + '">');
          base.$small.after(t.parent());
          // set base.$large again in case small area was cloned
          base.$large = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.largeArea);
        }
      }

      base.$lgInner = (base.$large.find('.' + n.largeInner).length) ?
        base.$large.find('.' + n.largeInner) :
        base.$large.wrapInner('<span class="' + n.largeInner + '"/>').find('.' + n.largeInner);

      if (!base.$wrap.find('.' + n.zoom).length) {
        base.$large.wrap('<div class="' + n.zoom + '"/>');
        base.$zoom = base.$wrap.find('.' + n.zoom);
      }

      if (o.edit && !base.edit) {
        base.edit = $('<span class="' + n.edit + '"></span>').appendTo(base.$zoom);
      }

      // wrap inner content with a span to get a more accurate width
      // get height from either the inner content itself or the children of the inner content since span will need
      // a "display:block" to get an accurate height, but adding that messes up the width
      base.$zoom.show();
      base.largeDim = [base.$lgInner.children().width(), Math.max(base.$lgInner.height(), base.$lgInner.children().height())];
      base.zoomDim = base.last = [base.$zoom.width(), base.$zoom.height()];
      base.$zoom.hide();

      base.smallDim = [base.$smInner.children().width(), base.$small.height()];
      base.$overlay = $('<div class="' + n.overly + '" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;" />').prependTo(base.$small);
      base.ratio = [
        base.largeDim[0] / (base.smallDim[0] || 1),
        base.largeDim[1] / (base.smallDim[1] || 1)
      ];

      base.$inner.add(base.$overlay).css({
        width: base.smallDim[0],
        height: base.smallDim[1]
      });

    };

    // Show small image - Setup
    base.showSmall = function() {
      base.state = true;
      base.$small.show();

      base.$zoom
        .removeClass(n.expanded)
        .addClass(n.windowed + ' ' + n.zoom)
        .css({
          width: base.zoomDim[0],
          height: base.zoomDim[1]
        });

      base.$inner.css({
        width: base.smallDim[0],
        height: base.smallDim[1]
      });

    };

    // Switch small and large on double click
    base.showLarge = function() {
      base.state = false;
      base.$small.hide();

      base.$zoom
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeIn(o.speed)
        .addClass(n.expanded)
        .removeClass(n.windowed + ' ' + n.zoom)
        .css({
          height: 'auto',
          width: 'auto'
        });

      base.$inner.css({
        width: base.largeDim[0],
        height: base.largeDim[1]
      });

      base.$large.css({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: base.largeDim[0],
        height: base.largeDim[1]
      });

    };

    // x,y coords -> George Washington in image demo
    // base.setTarget( 82, 50, [200,200] );

    // 'selector', [xOffset, yOffset], [zoomW, zoomH] -> Aug 26 in calendar demo
    // base.setTarget( '.day[rel=2009-08-26]', [0, 0], [200, 200] );
    base.setTarget = function(tar, sec, sz) {
      var t, x = 0,
        y = 0;
      clearTimeout(base.timer);

      if (!base.$zoom.hasClass(n.windowed)) {
        base.showSmall();
      }

      // x, y coords
      if (!isNaN(tar) && !isNaN(sec)) {
        x = parseInt(tar, 10);
        y = parseInt(sec, 10);
      } else if (typeof(tar) === 'string' && $(tar).length) {
        // '.selector', [xOffSet, yOffSet]
        t = $(tar);
        x = t.position().left + t.width() / 2 + (sec ? sec[0] || 0 : 0);
        y = t.position().top + t.height() / 2 + (sec ? sec[1] || 0 : 0);
      }

      base.zoomAt(x, y, sz);

      // add overlay
      if (o.overlay) {
        base.$overlay.addClass(n.overlay);
      }
      // hovered, but not really
      base.$smInner.addClass(n.hovered);

      // zoom window triggered
      base.$wrap.trigger('zoom', base);

    };

    // x, y, [zoomX, zoomY] - zoomX, zoomY are the dimensions of the zoom window
    base.zoomAt = function(x, y, sz, internal) {
      var sx = (sz ? sz[0] || 0 : 0) || base.last[0],
        sy = (sz ? sz[1] || sz[0] || 0 : 0) || base.last[1],
        sx2 = sx / 2,
        sy2 = sy / 2,
        ex = o.edge || (o.edge === 0 ? 0 : sx2 * 0.66), // 2/3 of zoom window
        ey = o.edge || (o.edge === 0 ? 0 : sy2 * 0.66), // allows edge to be zero
        m = parseInt(base.$inner.css('margin-left'), 10) || base.$inner.position().left || 0;
      // save new zoom size
      base.last = [sx, sy];
      // save x, y for external access
      base.current = [x, y];

      // show coordinates
      if (o.edit) {
        base.edit.html(Math.round(x) + ', ' + Math.round(y));
      }

      if ((x < -ex) || (x > base.smallDim[0] + ex) || (y < -ey) || (y > base.smallDim[1] + ey)) {
        base.hideZoom(internal);
        return;
      } else {
        // Sometimes the mouseenter event is delayed
        base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeIn(o.speed);
      }

      // center zoom under the cursor
      base.$zoom.css({
        left: x - sx2 + m,
        top: y - sy2,
        width: sx,
        height: sy
      });

      // match locations of small element to the large
      base.$large.css({
        left: -(x - o.offsetX - sx2 / 2) * base.ratio[0],
        top: -(y - o.offsetY - sy2 / 2) * base.ratio[1]
      });

    };

    base.hideZoom = function(internal) {
      if (internal && base.$smInner.hasClass(n.hovered)) {
        base.$wrap.trigger('unzoom', base);
      }
      base.last = base.zoomDim;
      base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeOut(o.speed);
      base.$overlay.removeClass(n.overlay);
      base.$smInner.removeClass(n.hovered);
      base.lastKey = null;
    };

    base.setEnabled = function(enable) {
      base.enabled = enable;
      if (enable) {
        var off = base.$small.offset();
        base.zoomAt(base.position.pageX - off.left, base.position.pageY - off.top, null, true);
      } else {
        base.showSmall();
        base.hideZoom();
        base.hovered = false;
      }
    };

    // Initialize zoomer
    base.init();

  };

  // class names used by anythingZoomer
  $.anythingZoomer.classNames = {
    namespace: '.anythingZoomer', // event namespace
    wrap: 'az-wrap',
    wrapInner: 'az-wrap-inner',
    large: 'az-large',
    largeInner: 'az-large-inner',
    small: 'az-small',
    smallInner: 'az-small-inner',
    overlay: 'az-overlay', // toggled class name
    overly: 'az-overly', // overlay unstyled class
    hovered: 'az-hovered',
    zoom: 'az-zoom',
    windowed: 'az-windowed', // zoom window active
    expanded: 'az-expanded', // zoom window inactive (large is showing)
    edit: 'az-coords', // coordinate window
    scrollzoom: 'az-scrollzoom'
  };

  $.anythingZoomer.defaultOptions = {
    // content areas
    smallArea: 'small', // class of small content area; the element with this class name must be inside of the wrapper
    largeArea: 'large', // class of large content area; this class must exist inside of the wrapper. When the clone option is true, it will add this automatically
    clone: false, // Make a clone of the small content area, use css to modify the style
    // appearance
    overlay: false, // set to true to apply overlay class "az-overlay"; false to not apply it
    speed: 100, // fade animation speed (in milliseconds)
    edge: 30, // How far outside the wrapped edges the mouse can go; previously called "expansionSize"
    offsetX: 0, // adjust the horizontal position of the large content inside the zoom window as desired
    offsetY: 0, // adjust the vertical position of the large content inside the zoom window as desired
    // functionality
    switchEvent: 'dblclick', // event that allows toggling between small and large elements - default is double click
    delay: 0, // time to delay before revealing the zoom window.
    // edit mode
    edit: false // add x,y coordinates into zoom window to make it easier to find coordinates
  };

  $.fn.anythingZoomer = function(options, second, sx, sy) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var anyZoom = $(this).data('zoomer');
      // initialize the zoomer but prevent multiple initializations
      if (/object|undefined/.test(typeof options)) {
        if (anyZoom) {
          anyZoom.update();
        } else {
          (new $.anythingZoomer(this, options));
        }
      } else if (anyZoom && (typeof options === 'string' || (!isNaN(options) && !isNaN(second)))) {
        if (/(en|dis)able/.test(options)) {
          anyZoom.setEnabled(options === 'enable');
        } else {
          anyZoom.setTarget(options, second, sx, sy);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.getAnythingZoomer = function() {
    return this.data('zoomer');
  };

  return $.anythingzoomer;

}));
```

```css
/* AnythingZoomer */

.az-wrap,
.az-small,
.az-large {
  position: relative;
}

.az-wrap-inner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* center small & large content */
}


/* This wraps the large image and hides it */

.az-zoom {
  background: #fff;
  border: #333 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
}


/* Class applied to az-mover when large image is windowed */

.az-windowed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Class applied to az-mover when large image is fully shown */

.az-expanded {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: static;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* overlay small area */

.az-overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  z-index: 10;
}


/* edit mode coordinate styling */

.az-coords {
  display: none;
  /* hidden when expanded */
}

.az-zoom .az-coords {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}


/* ZOOM CONTAINER */

.zoom {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.large {
  background: white;
}


/* FOR TEXT DEMO */

.small p {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 700px
}

.large p {
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 1400px;
}


/* FOR IMAGE DEMO */

.small img {
  width: 250px;
}

.large img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Image and Text Magnifier</title>

  <!-- anythingZoomer required -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anythingzoomer.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.anythingzoomer.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      // clone the text
      $(".zoom:first").anythingZoomer({
        clone: true
      });

      $(".zoom:last").anythingZoomer();

      $("button").click(function() {
        var state = $(this).text(); // enable or disable
        $(".zoom:eq(" + $(this).attr('data-id') + ")").anythingZoomer(state);
        $(this).text((state === "disable") ? "enable" : "disable");
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="double">

  <div id="main-content">

    <p>Double click within the section to toggle between the large and small versions.</p>

    <p><strong>Text Demo <button data-id="0">disable</button></strong></p>

    <div class="zoom">

      <div class="small">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
          est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      </div>

      <!-- the clone option will automatically make a div.large if it doesn't exist -->

    </div>

    <br>

    <p><strong>Image Demo <button data-id="1">disable</button></strong></p>


    <div class="zoom second">

      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg/1200px-Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg" alt="small rushmore">
      </div>

      <div class="large">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg/1200px-Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg" alt="big rushmore">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is nice, but what's the actual question?

Comment: @PeterMader How should I edit the function/code to reflect one button that controls the magnification of both image and text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works! Just loop through each of the elements using `.each` and then add the scroll zoomer function to it.when the button is pressed, loop through the elements again and apply the toggle functionality.

```js
;
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {

  "use strict";
  $.anythingZoomer = function(el, options) {
    var n, o, t, base = this;
    base.$wrap = $(el);
    base.wrap = el;

    // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
    base.$wrap.data('zoomer', base);

    base.version = '2.2.6';

    base.init = function() {
      base.options = o = $.extend({}, $.anythingZoomer.defaultOptions, options);

      // default class names
      n = $.anythingZoomer.classNames;

      // true when small element is showing, false when large is visible
      base.state = true;
      base.enabled = true;
      base.hovered = false;

      base.$wrap.addClass(n.wrap).wrapInner('<span class="' + n.wrapInner + '"/>');
      base.$inner = base.$wrap.find('.' + n.wrapInner);
      base.$small = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.smallArea);
      base.$large = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.largeArea);

      base.update();

      // Add classes after getting size
      base.$large.addClass(n.large);
      base.$small.addClass(n.small);

      base.$inner
        .bind('mouseenter' + n.namespace, function() {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          base.saved = base.enabled;
          base.hovered = true;
          if (o.delay) {
            clearTimeout(base.delay);
            base.enabled = false;
            base.delay = setTimeout(function() {
              base.enabled = base.saved;
              base.position.type = 'mousemove';
              base.$inner.trigger(base.position);
              base.reveal();
            }, o.delay);
          } else {
            base.reveal();
          }
        })
        .bind('mouseleave' + n.namespace, function() {
          base.hovered = false;
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          if (o.delay) {
            clearTimeout(base.delay);
            base.enabled = base.saved;
          }
          if (base.state && base.enabled) {
            // delay hiding to prevent flash if user hovers over it again
            // i.e. moving from a link to the image
            base.timer = setTimeout(function() {
              if (base.$zoom.hasClass(n.windowed)) {
                base.hideZoom(true);
              }
            }, 200);
          }
        })
        .bind('mousemove' + n.namespace, function(e) {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          base.position = e;
          if (!base.hovered) {
            return;
          }
          if (base.state && base.enabled) {
            clearTimeout(base.timer);
            // get current offsets in case page positioning has changed
            // Double demo: expanded text demo will offset image demo zoom window
            var off = base.$small.offset();
            base.zoomAt(e.pageX - off.left, e.pageY - off.top, null, true);
          }
        })
        .bind(o.switchEvent + (o.switchEvent !== '' ? n.namespace : ''), function() {
          if (!base.enabled) {
            return;
          }
          // toggle visible image
          if (base.state) {
            base.showLarge();
          } else {
            base.showSmall();
          }
        });

      base.showSmall();

      // add events
      $.each('initialized zoom unzoom'.split(' '), function(i, f) {
        if ($.isFunction(o[f])) {
          base.$wrap.bind(f, o[f]);
        }
      });

      base.initialized = true;
      base.$wrap.trigger('initialized', base);

    };

    base.reveal = function() {
      base.enabled = base.saved;
      if (base.state && base.enabled) {
        base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeIn(o.speed);
        if (o.overlay) {
          base.$overlay.addClass(n.overlay);
        }
        base.$smInner.addClass(n.hovered);
        base.$wrap.trigger('zoom', base);
      }
    };

    base.update = function() {

      // make sure the large image is hidden
      if (base.initialized) {
        base.showSmall();
      }

      base.$smInner = (base.$small.find('.' + n.smallInner).length) ?
        base.$small.find('.' + n.smallInner) :
        base.$small.wrapInner('<span class="' + n.smallInner + '"/>').find('.' + n.smallInner);
      base.$small.find('.' + n.overly).remove();

      if (o.clone) {
        t = base.$smInner.clone()
          .removeAttr('id')
          .removeClass(n.smallInner)
          .addClass(n.largeInner);
        if (base.$large.length) {
          // large area exists, just add content
          base.$large.html(t.html());
        } else {
          // no large area, so add it
          t.wrap('<div class="' + o.largeArea + '">');
          base.$small.after(t.parent());
          // set base.$large again in case small area was cloned
          base.$large = base.$wrap.find('.' + o.largeArea);
        }
      }

      base.$lgInner = (base.$large.find('.' + n.largeInner).length) ?
        base.$large.find('.' + n.largeInner) :
        base.$large.wrapInner('<span class="' + n.largeInner + '"/>').find('.' + n.largeInner);

      if (!base.$wrap.find('.' + n.zoom).length) {
        base.$large.wrap('<div class="' + n.zoom + '"/>');
        base.$zoom = base.$wrap.find('.' + n.zoom);
      }

      if (o.edit && !base.edit) {
        base.edit = $('<span class="' + n.edit + '"></span>').appendTo(base.$zoom);
      }

      // wrap inner content with a span to get a more accurate width
      // get height from either the inner content itself or the children of the inner content since span will need
      // a "display:block" to get an accurate height, but adding that messes up the width
      base.$zoom.show();
      base.largeDim = [base.$lgInner.children().width(), Math.max(base.$lgInner.height(), base.$lgInner.children().height())];
      base.zoomDim = base.last = [base.$zoom.width(), base.$zoom.height()];
      base.$zoom.hide();

      base.smallDim = [base.$smInner.children().width(), base.$small.height()];
      base.$overlay = $('<div class="' + n.overly + '" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;" />').prependTo(base.$small);
      base.ratio = [
        base.largeDim[0] / (base.smallDim[0] || 1),
        base.largeDim[1] / (base.smallDim[1] || 1)
      ];

      base.$inner.add(base.$overlay).css({
        width: base.smallDim[0],
        height: base.smallDim[1]
      });

    };

    // Show small image - Setup
    base.showSmall = function() {
      base.state = true;
      base.$small.show();

      base.$zoom
        .removeClass(n.expanded)
        .addClass(n.windowed + ' ' + n.zoom)
        .css({
          width: base.zoomDim[0],
          height: base.zoomDim[1]
        });

      base.$inner.css({
        width: base.smallDim[0],
        height: base.smallDim[1]
      });

    };

    // Switch small and large on double click
    base.showLarge = function() {
      base.state = false;
      base.$small.hide();

      base.$zoom
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeIn(o.speed)
        .addClass(n.expanded)
        .removeClass(n.windowed + ' ' + n.zoom)
        .css({
          height: 'auto',
          width: 'auto'
        });

      base.$inner.css({
        width: base.largeDim[0],
        height: base.largeDim[1]
      });

      base.$large.css({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: base.largeDim[0],
        height: base.largeDim[1]
      });

    };

    // x,y coords -> George Washington in image demo
    // base.setTarget( 82, 50, [200,200] );

    // 'selector', [xOffset, yOffset], [zoomW, zoomH] -> Aug 26 in calendar demo
    // base.setTarget( '.day[rel=2009-08-26]', [0, 0], [200, 200] );
    base.setTarget = function(tar, sec, sz) {
      var t, x = 0,
        y = 0;
      clearTimeout(base.timer);

      if (!base.$zoom.hasClass(n.windowed)) {
        base.showSmall();
      }

      // x, y coords
      if (!isNaN(tar) && !isNaN(sec)) {
        x = parseInt(tar, 10);
        y = parseInt(sec, 10);
      } else if (typeof(tar) === 'string' && $(tar).length) {
        // '.selector', [xOffSet, yOffSet]
        t = $(tar);
        x = t.position().left + t.width() / 2 + (sec ? sec[0] || 0 : 0);
        y = t.position().top + t.height() / 2 + (sec ? sec[1] || 0 : 0);
      }

      base.zoomAt(x, y, sz);

      // add overlay
      if (o.overlay) {
        base.$overlay.addClass(n.overlay);
      }
      // hovered, but not really
      base.$smInner.addClass(n.hovered);

      // zoom window triggered
      base.$wrap.trigger('zoom', base);

    };

    // x, y, [zoomX, zoomY] - zoomX, zoomY are the dimensions of the zoom window
    base.zoomAt = function(x, y, sz, internal) {
      var sx = (sz ? sz[0] || 0 : 0) || base.last[0],
        sy = (sz ? sz[1] || sz[0] || 0 : 0) || base.last[1],
        sx2 = sx / 2,
        sy2 = sy / 2,
        ex = o.edge || (o.edge === 0 ? 0 : sx2 * 0.66), // 2/3 of zoom window
        ey = o.edge || (o.edge === 0 ? 0 : sy2 * 0.66), // allows edge to be zero
        m = parseInt(base.$inner.css('margin-left'), 10) || base.$inner.position().left || 0;
      // save new zoom size
      base.last = [sx, sy];
      // save x, y for external access
      base.current = [x, y];

      // show coordinates
      if (o.edit) {
        base.edit.html(Math.round(x) + ', ' + Math.round(y));
      }

      if ((x < -ex) || (x > base.smallDim[0] + ex) || (y < -ey) || (y > base.smallDim[1] + ey)) {
        base.hideZoom(internal);
        return;
      } else {
        // Sometimes the mouseenter event is delayed
        base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeIn(o.speed);
      }

      // center zoom under the cursor
      base.$zoom.css({
        left: x - sx2 + m,
        top: y - sy2,
        width: sx,
        height: sy
      });

      // match locations of small element to the large
      base.$large.css({
        left: -(x - o.offsetX - sx2 / 2) * base.ratio[0],
        top: -(y - o.offsetY - sy2 / 2) * base.ratio[1]
      });

    };

    base.hideZoom = function(internal) {
      if (internal && base.$smInner.hasClass(n.hovered)) {
        base.$wrap.trigger('unzoom', base);
      }
      base.last = base.zoomDim;
      base.$zoom.stop(true, true).fadeOut(o.speed);
      base.$overlay.removeClass(n.overlay);
      base.$smInner.removeClass(n.hovered);
      base.lastKey = null;
    };

    base.setEnabled = function(enable) {
      base.enabled = enable;
      if (enable) {
        var off = base.$small.offset();
        base.zoomAt(base.position.pageX - off.left, base.position.pageY - off.top, null, true);
      } else {
        base.showSmall();
        base.hideZoom();
        base.hovered = false;
      }
    };

    // Initialize zoomer
    base.init();

  };

  // class names used by anythingZoomer
  $.anythingZoomer.classNames = {
    namespace: '.anythingZoomer', // event namespace
    wrap: 'az-wrap',
    wrapInner: 'az-wrap-inner',
    large: 'az-large',
    largeInner: 'az-large-inner',
    small: 'az-small',
    smallInner: 'az-small-inner',
    overlay: 'az-overlay', // toggled class name
    overly: 'az-overly', // overlay unstyled class
    hovered: 'az-hovered',
    zoom: 'az-zoom',
    windowed: 'az-windowed', // zoom window active
    expanded: 'az-expanded', // zoom window inactive (large is showing)
    edit: 'az-coords', // coordinate window
    scrollzoom: 'az-scrollzoom'
  };

  $.anythingZoomer.defaultOptions = {
    // content areas
    smallArea: 'small', // class of small content area; the element with this class name must be inside of the wrapper
    largeArea: 'large', // class of large content area; this class must exist inside of the wrapper. When the clone option is true, it will add this automatically
    clone: false, // Make a clone of the small content area, use css to modify the style
    // appearance
    overlay: false, // set to true to apply overlay class "az-overlay"; false to not apply it
    speed: 100, // fade animation speed (in milliseconds)
    edge: 30, // How far outside the wrapped edges the mouse can go; previously called "expansionSize"
    offsetX: 0, // adjust the horizontal position of the large content inside the zoom window as desired
    offsetY: 0, // adjust the vertical position of the large content inside the zoom window as desired
    // functionality
    switchEvent: 'dblclick', // event that allows toggling between small and large elements - default is double click
    delay: 0, // time to delay before revealing the zoom window.
    // edit mode
    edit: false // add x,y coordinates into zoom window to make it easier to find coordinates
  };

  $.fn.anythingZoomer = function(options, second, sx, sy) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var anyZoom = $(this).data('zoomer');
      // initialize the zoomer but prevent multiple initializations
      if (/object|undefined/.test(typeof options)) {
        if (anyZoom) {
          anyZoom.update();
        } else {
          (new $.anythingZoomer(this, options));
        }
      } else if (anyZoom && (typeof options === 'string' || (!isNaN(options) && !isNaN(second)))) {
        if (/(en|dis)able/.test(options)) {
          anyZoom.setEnabled(options === 'enable');
        } else {
          anyZoom.setTarget(options, second, sx, sy);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.getAnythingZoomer = function() {
    return this.data('zoomer');
  };

  return $.anythingzoomer;

}));
```

```css
/* AnythingZoomer */

.az-wrap,
.az-small,
.az-large {
  position: relative;
}

.az-wrap-inner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* center small & large content */
}


/* This wraps the large image and hides it */

.az-zoom {
  background: #fff;
  border: #333 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px #000;
}


/* Class applied to az-mover when large image is windowed */

.az-windowed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Class applied to az-mover when large image is fully shown */

.az-expanded {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: static;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* overlay small area */

.az-overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  z-index: 10;
}


/* edit mode coordinate styling */

.az-coords {
  display: none;
  /* hidden when expanded */
}

.az-zoom .az-coords {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}


/* ZOOM CONTAINER */

.zoom {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.large {
  background: white;
}


/* FOR TEXT DEMO */

.small p {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 700px
}

.large p {
  font-size: 32px;
  width: 1400px;
}


/* FOR IMAGE DEMO */

.small img {
  width: 250px;
}

.large img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Image and Text Magnifier</title>

  <!-- anythingZoomer required -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anythingzoomer.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.anythingzoomer.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      // clone the text
      $(".zoom").each(function(){
        $(this).anythingZoomer({clone: true});
      });

      $("button").click(function() {
        var state = $(this).text(); // enable or disable
        $(".zoom").each(function(){
          $(this).anythingZoomer(state);
        });
        $(this).text((state === "disable") ? "enable" : "disable");
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="double">

  <div id="main-content">

    <p>Double click within the section to toggle between the large and small versions.</p>
    <p><button>disable</button></p>
    <p><strong>Text Demo </strong></p>

    <div class="zoom">

      <div class="small">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
          est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      </div>

      <!-- the clone option will automatically make a div.large if it doesn't exist -->

    </div>

    <br>

    <p><strong>Image Demo


    <div class="zoom second">

      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg/1200px-Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg" alt="small rushmore">
      </div>

      <div class="large">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg/1200px-Dean_Franklin_-_06.04.03_Mount_Rushmore_Monument_%28by-sa%29-3_new.jpg" alt="big rushmore">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read the code but you could create the zoom using CSS 
    `btn:hover element{
    font-size:larger;
    }`